# Firebase Functions extremely slow resizing an image

Tags: javascript, firebase, imagemagick, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

Following the example mentioned [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/thumbnails) I used a firebase function to:

1) resize an uploaded photo to two different dimensions

2) The function would then retrieve the url and write it to the database so that the client app can retrieve the proper thumbnail when needed.

Unfortunately my plan never came to fruition as the firebase function completes its action very very slowly and it would be prohibitive for a client app to wait that long. 
Please bear in mind that I am not talking about function cold boot here...the function keeps being slow on every execution regardless of the image size or the number of images uploaded.

Is there any particular reason for this?? Am I doing something wrong??

Here is my code:

```
exports.generateThumbnailImages = storageRef.onChange(event => {

const object = event.data; 
const fileBucket = object.bucket; 
const filePath = object.name; 
const contentType = object.contentType; 
const resourceState = object.resourceState; 
const metageneration = object.metageneration; 

var folder=filePath.split('/')[0];
var fileName=filePath.split('/')[1];
// console.log(folder);
if (folder){
    if (folder.startsWith('images') && !fileName.includes('thumb')) {
        if(resourceState=='not_exists'){
            console.log('THIS IS A DELETION EVENT '+fileName);
        }
        else if(resourceState==='exists' && metageneration>1){
            console.log('THIS IS A METAGENERATION EVENT '+fileName);
        }   
        else if(resourceState==='exists'){
            console.log('THIS IS A CREATION EVENT '+fileName);
            const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
            const tempFilePath = '/tmp/${fileName}';
            const tempFilePathBig = '/tmp/${fileName}'+'Big';   
            bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempFilePath}).then(function() {
                bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempFilePathBig}).then(function() {
                    console.log('IMAGE DOWNLOADED LOCALLY TO', tempFilePath); 
                spawn('convert', [tempFilePath, '-thumbnail', '200x200', tempFilePath]).then(function() {
                    spawn('convert', [tempFilePathBig, '-thumbnail', '400x400', tempFilePathBig]).then(function() {
                        console.log('THUMBNAIL CREATED AT', tempFilePath);  
                    const thumbFilePath = filePath.replace(/(\/)?([^\/]*)$/, '$1thumb_$2');     
                    const thumbFilePathBig = filePath.replace(/(\/)?([^\/]*)$/, '$1thumb_Big$2');       
                    bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {destination: thumbFilePath}).then(function(){
                        bucket.upload(tempFilePathBig, {destination: thumbFilePathBig}).then(function(){
                            return;
                        });
                    });
                });
                });
            });
        });  
        }`
```

Comment: What performance do you see? What type of image are you resizing? What's the input and output size?

Comment: @Frank The average output (resize completion) I've measured is around 2-3 minutes (!) according to the function  logs. I have tried different image formats but mainly jpg and png. The input size  would also vary from  image to image but for test sake lets say a jpg, 1920x1080 with size 240kb and we require two thumbnails at 200x200 and 400x400 (although scaling occurs if the image is not rectangular so these dimensions are adjusted)

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I have the same problem. From what I can tell the promise returned by spawn doesn't respect the resolve and awaits a timeout?

Comment: @CodeKiwi the easiest way to help you through this is to watch these two firecasts:
1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lzEgwiSs-M
2:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDLpEn3PbmE
use the code presented as a base and then elaborate on it. 
It is working as expected!

Comment: @GiorgosS. Thanks for the heads up but I didn't find anything there that helped. I am already doing everything supposedly that is required.. any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @CodeKiwi that's very strange, what size are the images you are uploading? Can you post your code?

Comment: @GiorgosS. any solution 
I have exactly same issue :(

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen : any suggestion ?

Comment: @Andolad By following the above mentioned video tutorials you should able to bypass this issue if you are still having problems please post the code you are using for your functions in order to try and replicate the problem..

Comment: I have followed the same thing as the video is showing 
But still take time to finish the task.

Comment: https://codepen.io/fakhruddinabdi/post/issue-with-google-function

Comment: @GiorgosS. any suggestion ?

Comment: @Andolad Can you post some code here to have a look? Also can I suggest to start from scratch with the tutorial and then check if everything works properly.

Comment: @GiorgosS. This is my code 
https://codepen.io/fakhruddinabdi/post/issue-with-google-function

Comment: @Andolad normally you should post your code here in order to help other people as well or facilitate other answers...
I had a look and apparently as you said it works, so no errors there but as i said above try to replicate the exact code from the tutorial and see how it performs. Then from there on, start building your program based on the existing code and step by step you will find out what is causing the issue!

Comment: Thanks @GiorgosS. as i said before, i started from the sample code from firebase.
And the reason why i shared in codepen is that stackoverflow community doesn't allow sharing post as an answer here.
As i shared already and someone deleted it :)

Comment: Hi @GiorgosS. Not so much an explanation but I did manage to work around the issue. It seems that it is caused by an undocumented limitation of Firebase functions. However if the same code is hosted in Google App Engine (which supposedly what FB Functions is sitting on top of) everything goes as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to combine the two `spawn` commands into a single one, and not download / process the same image twice.

```js
bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempFilePath}).then(function() {
    spawn('convert', [tempFilePath,
                      '-thumbnail', '400x400',
                      '-write', $tempFilePath400,
                      '-thumbnail', '200x200',
                      '-write', $tempFilePath200,
                      'null:']).then(function() {
        // ...
```

I would also recommend exploring a queue-based background worker; such that, the client app will know that work has been deferred.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the issue is not whether or not the client will be informed about a potential delay (or if something is on a queue) but about the actual speed using the firebase functions. I did try to resize with one spawn command as well and the result was the same unfortunately.. around 2-3 minutes. Any other suggestions are welcome!